# $(X,d)$ is compact if each $(X,d_k)$ is compact

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

For each $k\in \mathbb N$, let $d_k$ be a metric on $X$ such that $d_k(x,y)\leq 1$ for all $x,y\in X$. Define a new metric,
$$d(x,y)=\sum_{k\geq 0}2^{-k}d_k(x,y)$$
Now show that if $(X,d_k)$ is compact for every $k$ then so is $(X,d)$.

Here is my attempt - let $(x_n)$ be an infinite sequence, I have extracted, through a diagonal argument, a subsequence $(x_{nn})$ which converges to, say, $y_k$ in the metric $d_k$, for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Now I do not understand how to proceed from here.

This question may have been already asked before, but I could not find it.

Comment: I am not sure the details of your argument, but there is a way to choose the subsequences so that the $y_k$ are actually all the same point, $y$. You can then show $x_{nn}\to y$ as well. To do this, given $\epsilon>0$, choose large enough $N$, then bound the first $N$ terms $2^{-n}d_n(x,y)$ by $2^{-n}\epsilon$, and the remaining terms by $2^{-n}\cdot 1$.

Comment: Can you explain why can you chose the limits to be the same?

Comment: Yes. Choose a subsequence $x_{n}^{(1)}$ converging to some point $y$ with respect to $d_1$. Then choose a sub-subsequence $x^{(2)}_n$ of $x_{n}^{(1)}$ converging to some point $y'$ with respect to $d_2$. Since subsequences must converge to the same point, you must have $x_n^{(2)}\to y$ with respect to $d_1$ as well, so $y'=y$. Continue choosing subsequences of subsequences of ... converging to $y$ with respect to $d_m$ for all $m$.

Comment: Why does $(x_n^{(2)})\rightarrow y$ in $d_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $(x_n^{(2)})\rightarrow y$ in $d_2$. This is exactly my whole issue. There may be no relation among $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Comment: (a) $x_{n}^{(1)}\to y$ in $d_1$. (b) $x_n^{(2)}$ is a subsequence of $x_{n}^{(1)}$. (c) If $w_n$ is a subsequence of $z_n$ and $z_n\to z$, then $w_n \to z$ as well.  (d) Therefore, $x_n^{(2)} \to y$ in $d_1$.

Comment: Yes but still, $x_n^{(2)}\rightarrow y$ w.r.t $d_1$ and $x_n^{(2)}\rightarrow y^{'}$ w.r.t $d_2$ does not imply that $y=y^{'}$.

Comment: Yes, sorry about all that, I was wrong.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: "Since subsequences must converge to the same point," is true for a given metric, but not necessarily true for two different metrics. But for this proof, it does not matter. Once you know that you have subsequences that converge (to $something$) in the metrics $d_j$ you only need to use the fact that the subsequence $x_{nn}$ is Cauchy in all the metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $(X,d)$ is complete because otherwise the result is false. Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $(X,d).$ Then, there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$, conveniently written $(x_{1m})$, such that $x_{1m}\to x_1\in (X,d_1).$ There is a now a subsequence  $(x_{2m})$, of $(x_{1m})$ such that  $(x_{2m})\to x_2\in (X,d_2)$ and of course  $(x_{2m})\to x_1\in (X,d_1)$ because it is a subsequence of $(x_{1m}).$

Continuing in this way, we obtain an array $(x_{nm})$ with the following properties:

$1).\ (x_{nm})\  \text {is a subsequence of}\ (x_{n'm}) \text{ whenever}\  n>n'$

$2).\  (x_{jm})\to x_j\in (X_j,d_j)\ \text{for all } 1\le j\le n$

Consider the diagonal of the array, i.e $(x_{nn})$ and let $m\in \mathbb N.$ Then, if $n\ge m$, the sequence  $(x_{nn})$ is a subsequence of the sequence $(x_{mm},x_{m(m+1)},x_{m(m+2)},\cdots),\ $ which is a tail of the sequence $(x_{mk})$ and so converges to $x_m\in (X_m,d_m).$

Now consider $d(x_{nn},x_{mm})=\sum_{k\geq 0}2^{-k}d_k(x_{nn},x_{mm}).$ Since $d_k<1$ for all $k$, we can choose $N$ large enough so that for $\epsilon>0,$

$3). d(x_{nn},x_{mm})\le \sum^N_{k=0}2^{-k}d_k(x_{nn},x_{mm})+\frac{\epsilon }{2}.$

For each $0\le k\le N$ there is an $N_k$ such that if $n,m>N_k,$ then $d_k(x_{nn},x_{mm})<\frac{\epsilon }{2N}$ so it suffices to take $N>\max {N_k}$ to see that if $n,m>N$ then

$4). \sum^N_{k=0}2^{-k}d_k(x_{nn},x_{mm})<N\cdot \frac{\epsilon }{2N}=\frac{\epsilon }{2}.$

Combining $3).$ and $4).$, we have now that $(x_{nn})$ is Cauchy and so $x_{nn}\to x\in (X,d).$

Comment: How do you know that $d_1$ and $d_2$ generate the same topology? Please explain to me why you can assume, $x_{2m}\rightarrow x_1$. This is exactly where I am stuck.

Comment: the metrics $d_j$ induce the topology of the $X_j$ so of course the topologies can be different. I do not see how this affects my proof though.

Comment: My question is this, suppose $y_n\rightarrow y $ w.r.t $d_1$ and $ y_n\rightarrow y^{'} $ w.r.t $ d_2 $, how can you say, $ y=y^{'} $?

Comment: Thanks. I see your point. So the assumption that $(X,d)$ is complete is crucial here.

Comment: Yes. I deleted my previous comment and placed it in the thread above, because I saw you were discussing it up there.

Answer (score 5):

The result is not true unless you have some compatibility conditions on $d_k$.  The problem being $(X,d)$ need not be complete.

**Example**: Let $X=[0,1]$, and let $\rho$ be the usual metric, $\rho'$ is the metric obtained from $d$ swapping $0,1$, i.e., $\rho'(x,y)=\rho(f(x),f(y))$ where
$$
f(t):=
\begin{cases}
1 & t=0\\
0 & t=1\\
t & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly $(X,\rho)$ and $(X,\rho')$ are compact.  Let $d_{odd}=\rho$ and $d_{even}=\rho'$.  Then the sequence $x_n=1/n$ is Cauchy but it doesn't converge in $d$. $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

However, if $X$ is $d$-complete (e.g., if $d_k$ are all topologically equivalent), then the result holds, since

**Claim**: Every sequence has a $d$-Cauchy subsequence.

*Gist of Proof*: Impose a constraint on how quickly subsequence converges at each $d_k$ and pass to diagonal subsequence.  For example, $d_k(x_{n_k(m)},x_{n_k(m')})<2^{-\min(m,m')}$, which implies a similar bound for $d$ when you pass to the diagonal subsequence.